# Error con condicional de PERL

Tags: perl

Estoy trabajando con una funcion que me permita extraer texto de un buzon de correo pero a pesar de que el buzon es cargado correctamente y el texto que busco a traves de un condicional aparentemente correcto si luego de la condicion elijo imprimir el resultado no lo imprimi ya que la condicion no se cumple, el codigo que aparece en el texto son 3 numeros más un espacion y 3 numeros mas separados por puntos, algo que se conoce como codigo dsn, ejemplo: 550 5.1.1 a continuación el codigo:

```html
foreach(split(/\n/, $body ) ){
next if(/^\s*$/);

if($_ =~ /^(\d{3}\s\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1})/ig ){
  $smtpCode = $1;
         print $smtpCode;
}
```

Cabe destacar que los uses y las variables están inicializadas.

Edicion:

Esa primera validacion logre repararla pero tengo otras tantas en la que tengo que depurar lo mas posible la data y son las siguientes:

```html
foreach(split(/\n/, $body ) ){
next if(/^\s*$/);

 if($_ =~ /^(\d{3}\s\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1})/ig ){
  $smtpCode = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^\d{3}\s\d{1}\.\d{1}\.\d{1}\s(.*)$/ig ){
  $smtpCodeDetail = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Final-Recipient:\sRFC822;\s([A-z0-9_\-\.]+@[A-z0-9_\-\.]+\.\w+)+$/ig ){
  $email = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Action:\s(\w+)$/){
  $smtpAction = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Status:\s(\d\.\d\.\d)$/){
  $smtpStatus = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Diagnostic-Code:\sSMTP;\s(.*)$/){
  $smtpDiagnosticCode = $1;

     if(($smtpDiagnosticCode =~ /(550\sSC\-[\d]{3})/ ) or ($smtpDiagnosticCode =~ /(550\sOU\-[\d]{3})/) or ($smtpDiagnosticCode =~ /(550\sDY\-[\d]{3})/) or ($smtpDiagnosticCode =~ /(421\sRP\-[\d]{3})/ ) ){
      $ipTempFiler = 1;
 }
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Remote-MTA:\sDNS;\s([A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)$/){
  $smtpRemoteMta = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^Last-Attempt-Date:\s[A-Za-z]+\,\s(\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d{4}\s[0-9:]{8}\s[0-9\-]{5})/ig ){
  $smtpLastAttemptDate = convert_date($1);
 }elsif($_ =~ /^X-RSidusuario:\s(\d+)$/){
  $usuarioId = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^X-RS-idadmin:\s(\d+)$/){
  $adminId = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^X-RS-idcamp:\s(\d+)$/){
  $campanaId = $1;
 }elsif($_ =~ /^X-RS-idlist:\s(\d+)$/){
  $listaId = $1;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Los paréntesis del primer if, sobran
- La parte "$_ =~ " también sobra, pero bueno, se puede dejar
- Los indicadores "/ig" sobran completamente
- Los cuantificadores "{1}" sobran
- En el patrón, el carácter '^' indica que el patrón debe coincidir con el inicio de la línea. Si no está al principio, no encuentra el resto.

Comment: Repare la validacion y me paso hermano, eres un crack pero tengo como 10 validaciones mas, si te las coloco todas me das una mano con eso?

Comment: Pasa por la validacion pero la variable me la muestra vacia.

Comment: Disculpe amigo mala, mi es lo malo de ser novato, no quite todo lo que me dijiste e igual no muestra nada.

Comment: Mira como reduci el codigo: foreach(split(/\n/, $body ) ){

    $numero = $numero + 1;
    print $numero . "\n";
    next if /^\s*$/; #Elimine parentesis
    
    if(/^\d{3}\s\d\.\d\.\d/ ){
     $smtpCode = $1;
                                        print $smtpCode;

Comment: Este sitio es muy incómodo para mandar código, como estás viendo. Te podemos atender mejor en el sitio perlenespanol.com

Comment: Como te contacto en esa pagina? No acepta registros, me da error con el email y el captcha no funciona.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso. Se lo he indicado al dueño del foro. Esperemos que lo arregle en unos minutos, y te aviso.

Comment: Hola. Parece que ya está cambiado el captcha del registro. Mira a ver si puedes registrarte ahora. Entra en el foro Básico y deja tu pregunta, y entre todos lo estudiaremos.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya me registré